# multiple keys in nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, nested, python-3.4

**Code**:

```
from operator import itemgetter
names = {
    'Bucky': 'Roberts',
    'Tom': 'Roberts',
    'Bernie' : 'Zunks',
    'Jenna' : 'Hayes',
    'Sally': 'Jones',
    'Amanda':'Roberts',
    'Tom':'Williams',
    'Dean':'Hayes',
    'Bernie':'Barbie',
    'Tom':'Jones'
    }
users = []
for k,v in names.items():
    users.append({'fname':k,'lname':v})
print(users)
for x in sorted(users, key=itemgetter('fname')):
    print(x)
```

**Problem**: For the last `for` loop (sorting one) to show all entries of dictionary `names`, I need all the entries i.e. duplicate keys (one-to-many mapping) also. But 2 `Tom(s)` and 1 `Bernie` are missed out while creating nested dictionary `users`. How can it be avoided using python 3.4?

Comment: The problem is when you define `names`.

Comment: You cannot have duplicate keys in a `dict` so when you're creating the `names` dictionary your `Tom` and `Bernie` keys get overwritten by the latter entries. Store the entries as tuples in a `list` (or a `set` if you don't care for order) if you want to keep the duplicate entries.

Comment: **@Rex5**, better is to have a single key with multiple values i.e. you can have a key (common **fname**) pointing to a list of corresponding **lname**s. **e.g.** `{'Bernie': ['Zunks', 'Barbie']}`. You can check the full example in my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few possible improvements, but to your main issue, use the full name and a `set` as your structure, and `split` on space to create the other dict (which I am not sure you need):

```
names = {
    'Bucky Roberts',
    'Tom Roberts',
    'Bernie Zunks',
    'Jenna Hayes',
    'Sally Jones',
    'Amanda Roberts',
    'Tom Williams',
    'Dean Hayes',
    'Bernie Barbie',
    'Tom Jones'
}

users = []
for name in names:
    k, v = name.split()
    users.append({'fname':k,'lname':v})
for x in sorted(users, key=itemgetter('fname')):
    print(x)
```

Produces:

```
{'fname': 'Amanda', 'lname': 'Roberts'}
{'fname': 'Bernie', 'lname': 'Barbie'}
{'fname': 'Bernie', 'lname': 'Zunks'}
{'fname': 'Bucky', 'lname': 'Roberts'}
{'fname': 'Dean', 'lname': 'Hayes'}
{'fname': 'Jenna', 'lname': 'Hayes'}
{'fname': 'Sally', 'lname': 'Jones'}
{'fname': 'Tom', 'lname': 'Williams'}
{'fname': 'Tom', 'lname': 'Jones'}
{'fname': 'Tom', 'lname': 'Roberts'}
```

EDIT: using tuples and adding `Betty Sue Johnson`:

```
names = {
    ('Bucky', 'Roberts'),
    ('Betty Sue', 'Johnson'),
    ('Tom', 'Roberts'),
    ('Bernie', 'Zunks'),
    ('Jenna', 'Hayes'),
    ('Sally', 'Jones'),
    ('Amanda', 'Roberts'),
    ('Tom', 'Williams'),
    ('Dean', 'Hayes'),
    ('Bernie', 'Barbie'),
    ('Tom', 'Jones')
}

for each in sorted([{'fname':n[0], 'lname':n[1]} for n in names], key=itemgetter('fname')):
    print(each)
```

With output:

```
{'fname': 'Amanda', 'lname': 'Roberts'}
{'fname': 'Bernie', 'lname': 'Zunks'}
{'fname': 'Bernie', 'lname': 'Barbie'}
{'fname': 'Betty Sue', 'lname': 'Johnson'}
{'fname': 'Bucky', 'lname': 'Roberts'}
{'fname': 'Dean', 'lname': 'Hayes'}
{'fname': 'Jenna', 'lname': 'Hayes'}
{'fname': 'Sally', 'lname': 'Jones'}
{'fname': 'Tom', 'lname': 'Roberts'}
{'fname': 'Tom', 'lname': 'Williams'}
{'fname': 'Tom', 'lname': 'Jones'}
```

Comment: Betty Sue Johnson is going to hate this. Better to put first and last names in tuples.

Comment: That does serves the pupose esp. the split() step . I'll do try storing the entries as tuples in a list as @zwer suggested. TY.

Comment: @tdelaney added an example with tuples and less code (and poor ole Betty Sue)

Answer (score 3):

A `dict` cannot have duplicate keys, you might want to consider another data structure such as a list of tuples.

```
from operator import itemgetter

names = [
    ('Bucky', 'Roberts'),
    ('Tom', 'Roberts'),
    ('Bernie', 'Zunks'),
    ('Jenna', 'Hayes'),
    ('Sally', 'Jones'),
    ('Amanda','Roberts'),
    ('Tom', 'Williams'),
    ('Dean', 'Hayes'),
    ('Bernie', 'Barbie'),
    ('Tom', 'Jones')
    ]

users = [{'fname': k,'lname': v} for k, v in names]
```

Answer (score 2):

Dictionaries cannot have duplicate keys, so the original data would need to be changed into something else...such as a list of full-name strings that contained both the first and last name separated by spaces.

Before Python 3.6, the items in dictionaries are unorderd, so you could instead store the results in a `collections.OrderedDict` subclass to preserve the order that the keys were inserted if you wished to have it retained (which will continue work in Python 3.6 as well as earlier versions).

Putting everthing together, would result in something like this:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from operator import itemgetter
from pprint import pprint

names = ['Bucky Roberts',
         'Tom Roberts',
         'Bernie Zunks',
         'Jenna Hayes',
         'Amanda Roberts',
         'Tom Williams',
         'Dean Hayes',
         'Bernie Barbie',
         'Tom Jones',]

users = OrderedDict()
for name in sorted(names):
    fname, lname = name.split()
    users.setdefault(fname, []).append(lname)

pprint(users)
```

Output:

```
OrderedDict([('Amanda', ['Roberts']),
             ('Bernie', ['Zunks', 'Barbie']),
             ('Bucky', ['Roberts']),
             ('Dean', ['Hayes']),
             ('Jenna', ['Hayes']),
             ('Tom', ['Roberts', 'Williams', 'Jones'])])
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

Consider the below

```
from collections import defaultdict

names = defaultdict(list)

names['Bucky'].append('Roberts')

names['Tom'].append('Roberts')

names['Bernie'].append('Zunks')

names['Jenna'].append('Hayes')

names['Sally'].append('Jones')

names['Amanda'].append('Roberts')

names['Tom'].append('Williams')

names['Dean'].append('Hayes')

names['Bernie'].append('Barbie')

names['Tom'].append('Jones')
print names
```

Outputs:

```
defaultdict(list,
            {'Amanda': ['Roberts'],
             'Bernie': ['Zunks', 'Barbie'],
             'Bucky': ['Roberts'],
             'Dean': ['Hayes'],
             'Jenna': ['Hayes'],
             'Sally': ['Jones'],
             'Tom': ['Roberts', 'Williams', 'Jones']})
```

***Explanation***

`names = defaultdict(list)` initializes a dictionary that creates an empty list instead of throwing a  `KeyError` when a key that doesn't exist is queried.

Therefore you can just append to new keys as though they were in the dict.

Making the users list can be as below

```
users = []

for fname in names:
    for lname in names[fname]:
        users.append({'fname': fname, 'lname': lname})
```

Answer (score 1):

**@Rex5**, dictionary is defined as an unordered collection of items with unique keys.

> **Keys** should be immutable data items but **values**  can be mutable/immutable both.

So, definition itself is filtering out the duplicated values while creating **names** dictionary hence there is no chance of having the duplicated copies inside for loops.

Have a look at the below sample example. I have also modified your code example after this.

> Focus on keys **Sam** and **Kim**.

```
import json

# Creating list of users (Dictionary) with duplicated keys
users = {
"Sam": "Smith",
"Samuel": "Badri",
"Kim": "Jones",
"Jim": "Hollowen",
"Sam": "Paul",
"Joel": "Brown",
"Kim": "Fillo",
"Sam": "Koelli",
"Tinnu": "Timmon"
}

# Pretty printing the dictionary
# Keys, Sam & Kim will appear only once even after their multiple occurrences
print( json.dumps(users, indent=4))

# {
#    "Kim": "Fillo",
#    "Sam": "Koelli",
#    "Tinnu": "Timmon",
#    "Jim": "Hollowen",
#    "Joel": "Brown",
#    "Samuel": "Badri"
# }
```

> I have also tried to provide an alternative answer that fulfills the need as follows (What I did is I just modified the dictionary and for loop).

```
from operator import itemgetter
names = {
    'Bucky': 'Roberts',
    'Tom': ['Roberts', 'Williams', 'Jones'],
    'Bernie' : ['Zunks', 'Barbie'],
    'Jenna' : 'Hayes',
    'Sally': 'Jones',
    'Amanda':'Roberts',
    'Dean':'Hayes',
}

users = []
for k,v in names.items():
    if type(v) == type([]):
        for lname in v:
            users.append({'fname': k, 'lname': lname})
    else:
        users.append({'fname':k, 'lname':v})

print(users)

"""
[{'lame': 'Zunks', 'fname': 'Bernie'}, {'lname': 'Barbie', 
'fname': 'Bernie'}, {'lname': 'Jones', 'fname': 'Sally'}, 
{'lname': 'Hayes', 'fname': 'Jenna'}, {'lname': 'Roberts', 
'fname': 'Amanda'}, {'lname': 'Roberts', 'fname': 'Bucky'}, 
{'lname': 'Hayes', 'fname': 'Dean'}, {'lname': 'Roberts', 
'fname': 'Tom'}, {'lname': 'Williams', 'fname': 'Tom'}, 
{'lname': 'Jones', 'fname': 'Tom'}]
"""

for x in sorted(users, key=itemgetter('fname')):
    print(x)

"""
{'lname': 'Roberts', 'fname': 'Amanda'}
{'lname': 'Zunks', 'fname': 'Bernie'}
{'lname': 'Barbie', 'fname': 'Bernie'}
{'lname': 'Roberts', 'fname': 'Bucky'}
{'lname': 'Hayes', 'fname': 'Dean'}
{'lname': 'Hayes', 'fname': 'Jenna'}
{'lname': 'Jones', 'fname': 'Sally'}
{'lname': 'Roberts', 'fname': 'Tom'}
{'lname': 'Williams', 'fname': 'Tom'}
{'lname': 'Jones', 'fname': 'Tom'}
"""
```

Comment: i'll better stick to default dictionary.